time.h functions won't work properly in certain versions of toolchain
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    struct timeval tv = { .tv_sec = 25, .tv_usec = 0 };
    settimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    while(true)
    {
        time_t now;
        time(&now);
        printf("Current epoch time: %ld\n", now);
        delay(1000);
    }
}
void loop(){}

I set the system time epoch to 25 and the read it using time(&now) and print it. the initial printed value is random but around 60 but afterwards it switches between 1081 and 1080 periodically.
serial monitor output (when compiled using 12.2.0 or 11.2.0 version):
Current epoch time: 69
Current epoch time: 1081
Current epoch time: 1081
Current epoch time: 1081
Current epoch time: 1081

serial monitor output (compiled using 8.4.0 version):
Current epoch time: 25
Current epoch time: 26
Current epoch time: 27
Current epoch time: 28
Current epoch time: 29


There is probably a problem in your environment. Can your share more information?
You Platform-IO in VS Code with the Arduino-SDK?
Which MCU+board are you using?
How does your platformio.ini look like, especially board, platform_version , build_flags, and platform?
Is there any additional *.c or *.cpp file in you project whose constructors might run in parallel?
You can try to explicitly disable Wifi to make sure it is not using ntp to update the system clock:
WiFi.disconnect(true);  // Ensure Wi-Fi is off

When you earlier had a sketch running, the Wifi credentials are automatically stored in flash and might get used and also enable ntp on startup automatically.
To clear those settings you should erase the whole flash or you can run this code once:
  WiFi.eraseAP();

Therefore it is a good idea to disable the persistence feature before activating  Wifi also to reduce FLASH wearing-out:
WiFi.persistent(false); // don't save credentials in FLASH to disable auto reconnect
WiFi.begin("YourAp", "YourPassword");

See also here

This would be easier to answer authoritatively with a reproducible test case that would include details like what hardware this is running on.  I wrote out my notes while thinking about it, but if you get only one copy-paste answer, try my last block.
I'm skeptical this is the entirety of the code running on the system, even if this is all of YOUR code. It seems likely that SOMETHING else is changing it. Perhaps networking on the other core (we don't know if you have one or two cores) is still booting? There are boards that include hardware RTC and dozens of different versions of ESP-IDF as well as a dozen or so different ESP32 core chips. With the info you've given, none of us can exactly put that test case in a debugger and see what's going on.
Your code should test the return values on ALL system codes. Notably, if time() is actually returning a -1, the contents of |now| will be indeterminate as it's a stack local. Use the other form of the time(2) calling convention just to make it more obvious.
   time_t now = time(NULL); 

   if (now > 0)
     printf("Current epoch time: %ld\n", now);
   else
     printf("Time lost its mind and returned %ld\n", now);

In c++, I'd spell that
if (time_t now = time(NULL) > 0) ... success
just to reduce the scope of now, but we don't know what language this is trying to be.
While low values are convenient, does a more contemporary time - hopefully in the forward direction - do the same thing? As a dirty test, I'd change the 25 in
struct timeval tv = { .tv_sec = 1723931000, .tv_usec = 0 };
to a value from https://www.epochconverter.com/timestamp-list just to save myself the pain of dealing with the C functions that parse date-time values. (As you see, I'd pick one that's now-ish, but ending in 000 while chasing this...)  Does it now jump (and stay?) forward 180 and go back to now?
Are the times displayed at one second intervals or is the delay (which only promises to spin AT LEAST that long) actually sleeping longer sometimes? Or is the device actually pausing a bit, possibly trying to initialize something that's not attached, so you're seeing more than one wall second pass?
Of course, using arduino-style delay with such long values on a multi-core RTOS (Arduino is a layer of crud above ESP-IDF which has an entire implementation of FreeRTOS between them) On most ESP32s, Arduino is actually a task that's brought up on the second core and if you're trying to run this right after a reset, it's possible that something you can't see is still bringing up clock enables, spin-waiting for hardware that may or not be there, and generally setting up shop when things are called.
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    struct timeval tv = { .tv_sec = 25, .tv_usec = 0 };
    settimeofday(&tv, NULL);
}


void loop(){
       time_t now = time(NULL); 

       if (now > 0)
         printf("Current epoch time: %ld\n", now);
       else
         printf("Time lost its mind and returned %ld\n", now);
}

If it turns out that helps but there's still something ELSE that causes a jump, then do your things after ALL the startups are done as I dont think the ordering of all the setups is guaranteed. You can help that somewhat by making that more explicit. IIRC, all the constructors  (setups) are run first before calling loop(), so maybe take all these attempts at once and split it up like:
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop(){
  struct timeval tv = { .tv_sec = 1723931000, .tv_usec = 0 };
  if (settimeofday(&tv, NULL)) {
     fprintf(stderr, "settimeofday failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      exit(1); // or whatever else for catastrophic failure.
  }
enter code here
  for(;;) {
    time_t now = -1;
    if (now > 0)
      printf("Current epoch time: %ld\n", now);
    else
      printf("Time lost its mind and returned %ld. %s\n", now, strerror(errno));
  }

}
You may have to add an include for errno.h and maybe an extern int errno depending on exactly how POSIX-y the system tries to be.
Sidebar: it looks like there's been some recent pain if settimeofday is called but the time zones haven't (yet?) been brought up (https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/10876#issuecomment-1451684572) but it's unclear how that bit of ESP-IDF wisdom maps to Arduino-land. I tracked the implemention of settime up to https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/newlib/time.c which looks like it's doing the right thing, but if there's an outstanding call to https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/d7ca8b94c852052e3bc33292287ef4dd62c9eeb1/components/newlib/time.c#L48 already scheduled, that might fire after you've called settimeofday.  It's just really hard to pencil whip it.
Sources:
https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s3/api-reference/system/system_time.html
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/time.html
